# SyntaxError:Can't assign to function call

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am new to python and programming and I'm doing an online course. The code to be written is to calculate who has sent most number of emails in a txt files and to only read the lines which start with **"From"**. My code is

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()
for line in handle:
   if line.startswith("From"):
        wds =  line.split()
        if len(wds)<2: continue
        email = wds[1]
        print email
   counts(email) = counts.get(email , 0)+1
```

The error is on the last line of the code where I try to add the email address to the dictionary which gives me the error **SyntaxError: Can't assign to function call** .

I have  the working code. But I am trying a new code for this.

**If anything is unclear please ask**

Comment: This: `counts(email)` is a function call. You cannot set it to a value.

Comment: For future problems: the error was spot on. It might be a bit cryptic to a beginner, but some research goes a long way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write to a `dict`, use square brackets:

```
counts[email] = ...
```

instead of

```
counts(email) = ...
```

Round brackets `()` are used to call a function, so the interpreter thinks you are trying assign a value to a function call.